# Physical quantity that can be expressed using multiple fundamental units

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, si-units

Any physical quantity can be represented as a product of powers of fundamental SI units.For example, Force has dimensions $[\text{kg}\ \text{m}\ \text{s}^{-2}]$ and has three fundamental units. Likewise, what is the physical quantity that has the most fundamental SI units? I can create an arbitrary physical quantity with dimensions $[\text{kg}\ \text{m}\ \text{s}\ \text{A}\ \text{mol}]$ but I am looking for a quantity that is meaningful.

Comment: This post (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: This isn't strictly a list question, although it might turn into one.

Comment: Quantities describing the magnetic field can be quite complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make any arbitrary unit made of such things but they may not be particularly useful units, of course. The unit listed in the SI standard with the most "fundamental units" is the molar entropy, $\text{m}^2. \text{kg} .\text{s}^{-2} .\text{K}^{-1} . \text{mol}^{-1}$.

Comment: I had bet on these five to be the SI units to be used if there was a physical quantity.

Comment: Modified the question as per your suggestion.